# Как получить доступ к аппаратным кнопкам на Android из Kivy jnius

Tags: java, android, python, kivy

Оборачиваю классы и пытаюсь обратиться к их методам и значениям:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from jnius import autoclass

#KeyEvent = autoclass('android.view.KeyEvent.Callback')
>>Event = autockass('android.view.KeyEvent')
>>Down = autockass('android.view.KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN')
class Container(GridLayout):
    def change_text(self):
        st = str(Down)
```

Но при любых обращениях к методам этих классов приложение разваливается.

Comment: Для начала неплохо было бы показать стектрейс ошибки.

Comment: Это начальный опыт работы с jnius, собираю Buildozer, ошибок нет, а на смартфоне просто разваливается при запуске. Примеры с обертыванием других java классов работают, а на аппаратные кнопки не смог найти ни чего пока, вопросы похожие есть но без ответов :(

Comment: Чтобы получить лог ошибки при запуске программы на Android, установите на компьютер `Android Debug Bridge`, откройте терминал, подключите мобильное устройство с вашей программой к компьютеру посредством `USB` кабеля, введите в терминал команду `adb logcat | grep python`, нажмите `Enter` и запустите приложение на мобильном. Смотрите лог в терминале.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду пробовать. Если есть возможность помочь с кодом буду благодарен.